# Bootstrap Collapsed Nav-bar doesn´t close on click

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I´m using Bootstrap for my website and after lot of search in stackoverflow I´m still unable to solve my issue.

The menu has some dropdown and everything works well unless one thing. The collapsed menu doesn´t close ever.

I´m using bootstrap-transition.js v2.3.2 and bootswatch v3.3.1+2.

Here is my code:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
    <div class="container">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
        </div>
        <div class="navbar-collapse collapse navbar-responsive-collapse">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li><a href="#"><img src="icon.png" alt="icon" /></a>
                <li><a href="#">Try it!!</a></li>
                <li class="dropdown">
                    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Rank<b class="caret"></b></a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                        <li><a href="#">Rank</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">User</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Chat</a></li>
            </ul>      
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                <li class="dropdown">
                    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Language<b class="caret"></b></a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                    <li><a href="#">English</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li class="dropdown" id="menu1">
                    <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Log in<b class="caret"></b></a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Works when I test it locally. Your HTML suggests you're still using Bootstrap 3.x so I would recommend making sure that your various CSS and JavaScript assets reflect that.

Comment: @Robert: After editing the question, I created a fiddle and the fiddle works, however i can't make the website work, if you want to check it is [ClashOfClansManager](http://www.clashofclansmanager.com). At this point I've run out of ideas and I won't transfer to Bootstrap 4 as is an old website with little maintenance

Comment: Your description suggests the issue is related to some additional CSS or JavaScript on the live site that would conflict with the `data-target="collapse"` behavior.